# count and average certain pixels in image with MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, for-loop, count

I have one image in bmp format, with size of 512*512.  I want to count the number of pixels with values more than 11 and then find the average of these pixels.  Here is my code.  I don't know what is the problem but the sum of pixel values is wrong and it is always 255.  I tried with different images.

Could you please help me to figure it out?

```
A=imread('....bmp');

sum=0; count=0;

for i=1:512    
   for j=1:512
      if (A(i,j)>=11)
        sum=sum+A(i,j);
        count=count+1;
      end
   end
end

disp('Number of pixels grater than or equal to 11')
disp(count)

disp('sum')
disp(sum)

disp('Average')
Avrg=sum/count;
disp(Avrg)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Why doesn't your code work**

Difficult to tell, could you display a portion of your matrix and the size using something like

```
disp(A(1:10,1:10))
disp(size(A))
% possibly also the min and max...
disp(min(A(:))
disp(max(A(:))
```

just to be sure the format of `A` is as you expect - `imread` could have given you a `512x512x3` matrix if the image was read in color, or the image may be in the interval [0,1].

**Better approach**

Once you're sure that the matrix is indeed 512x512, and has values above 11, you're best off by generating a mask, i.e.

```
mask = A > 11;
numabove11 = sum(mask(:));
avabove11 = mean(A(mask));
```

Also in your code you use `>=` i.e. greater than or equal to, but you say 'greater than' - pick which you want and be consistent.

**Explanation**

So what do these 3 lines do?

1. Generate a logical matrix, same size as `A` that is `true` wherever `A > 11`, else `false`.
2. Sum the logical matrix, which means sum values that are `1` everywhere that `A > 11`, else 0 (boolean values are converted to floats for this summation).
3. Index in to matrix A using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1), and take the mean of those values.

**Avoid shadowing builtins**

In your code you use the variable `sum` - this is bad practice as there is a builtin matlab function with the same name, which becomes unusable if you use a variable of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar problem and actually the solution lies in the fact that matlab stores `A(i,j)` in uint8 format whose maximum value is 255, so, just change the statement:

```
sum=sum+A(i,j);
```

to

```
sum=sum+double(A(i,j));
```

I hope this helps.